# React Router With Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, react-router

If my url path starts with a `/-IDNUMBER`, I want the react-router to render the `Home` Component. For example if the URL is:

`/-MX9EnU6aOtENtdQxLvF` or `/-MX9F3z22XrMjlgEAHUI` it should render the `Home` Component. I assume the best way to do this is to use Regex (let me know if there is a better way). Here is what I tried:

`<Route path="/^-" component={Home} />`.
This is not working, I tried other variations which also don't work. Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: I think this [Shaya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723370/react-router-4-regex-paths-match-doesnt-find-parameters) solves your problem.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723370/react-router-4-regex-paths-match-doesnt-find-parameters) solves your problem!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for finding that, I'm still having problems with getting the Regex to work. I don't know how long the ID Number can be, it can be as long as possible. Therefore I need a different answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could try something like:

```js
const idRegex = '([0-9a-zA-Z]*)';

...

<Route path={`/-${idRegex}`} component={Home} />
```

I couldn't find the official documentation, but basically, if you open `()` in a path string, you can include a Regex expression in it. So, I basically wrote this simple Regex Expression that is going to match every number, letter and especial character.

So finally, when you add `` path={`/-${idRegex}`} ``, it's going to consider a a router as you need, `/-USERID`, and render the proper Component. The final Path String is going to be `/-([0-9a-zA-Z]*)`.

I hope it's clear enough, and you can apply it furthermore to some other situations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works. Can you please explain how it works.

Comment: I just updated my answer. I hope it clarifies.